Identities involving exterior and interior derivatives
I am reading Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics and get stuck in one of the practice problem.
The problem is if $\tau$ is the 3-D volume element, we have
$$i_{\nabla\times(\textbf{a}\times \textbf{b})}\tau=di_\textbf{a}i_{\textbf{b}}\tau$$
$$(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{a})\
\tau=di_\mathbf{a}\tau$$
The second identity seems easier to prove so I begin with this one. First, we have $$\tau=\frac{1}{6}\epsilon_{ijk}dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k$$
However, then I get stuck on how to properly represent $i_\textbf{a}\tau$. I use brute force to calculate how it acts on two vectors $\textbf{u},\textbf{v}$ such that
$$(i_\textbf{a}\tau)(\textbf{u},\textbf{v})=\tau(\textbf{a},\textbf{u},\textbf{v})=\epsilon_{ijk}a_iu_jv_k$$
Hence, we should have
$$i_\textbf{a}\tau=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}a_i\ dx^j\wedge dx^k$$
Bur I am not sure how to go directly from the expression of $\tau$ to the expression of $i_\textbf{a}\tau$, without explicitly using two auxiliary vectors $\textbf{u},\textbf{v}$ to see what the final expression should look like.
But assuming this step is correct for now, we have
$$di_\textbf{a}\tau=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_la_i\ dx^l\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k$$
Now I get stuck again on which formula I should apply to render it into the final form
$$(\partial_la_l)\frac{1}{6}\epsilon_{ijk}dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k$$
where the first part gives the divergence of $\textbf{a}$ and the second part gives the volume element.
Can anyone help me on that?
